# What is wrong with my calculated column formula?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, power-automate

I have a SharePoint list which contains a column which displays a Custom Item ID created by concatenating the ID field and the last 2 digits of the year (like this 01-21).

In some circumstances it is necessary to create a duplicate of an existing item. in this case, when  the new item is created, the user inputs the original items Custom Item ID into a field called OriginalID to maintain a link between the copy and the original.

I want to use a Power Automate flow update fields in the original item when the copy is created. To do this I have created a calculated field which should 'reverse-engineer' the ID column from the OriginalID column by removing the last 3 characters (the hyphen and year digits) from the OriginalID.

This is what my formula looks like:

```
=LEFT([OriginalID],LEN([OriginalID]-3))
```

It is set to return a text string as is the OriginalID field.

when all the necessary fields have correct data input into them the calculated column returns a #VALUE! Error.

Can anyone assist with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any of the below formula, it should work for you:

```
=LEFT([OriginalID], LEN([OriginalID])-3)
```

OR

```
=LEFT([OriginalID], INT(FIND("-", [OriginalID])-1))
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Microsoft documentation**:

1. [LEFT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/left-function-913824b4-fc42-4c8c-9229-0eaa57dcdf49)
2. [LEN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/len-function-038f2e0d-57d3-4f35-ae74-9a79d66e8fc2)
3. [FIND function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-function-06213f91-b5be-4544-8b0b-2fd5a775436f)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the formula shall be like `=LEFT([OriginalID],LEN([OriginalID])-3)`

The parentheses are not in the right position